# Wireless drivers & lack of packages?

Tags: wireless, 14.04

I'm attempting to install wireless drivers for my USB WiFi dongle. I installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS server.

I got the Linux drivers from here: http://www.edimax.com/edimax/merchandise/merchandise_detail/data/edimax/global/wireless_adapters_n150/ew-7811un

So I transferred it via USB stick and found Ubuntu did not come with unzip..? Concerning. Told me to use apt-get, but of course I have no wireless yet.

So I got it unzipped on a Windows PC and moved to Ubuntu via USB stick, and started to install it. I ran the install script and it finished up with a `make`... except Ubuntu did not come with `make` either!

At this point I'm stuck. No internet to apt-get it, and no make to get internet. No wire connection either.

What do I do? I do have a USB stick I can transfer from a Windows machine. Anything I can use that to accomplish it? Transfer a compiled file? (But I don't have another Ubuntu machine)

Or is there a standard wireless driver I can use that would be located on my install USB?

Comment: try with instaling common wifi drivers containing packages: `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`

Comment: @user308564 I can use that without internet?

Comment: you need to borrow a dongle for this. (or adsl)

Comment: @user308564 I have a USB stick. You mean that? The WiFi dongle I have needs these drivers... which I cannot install without make

Answer (score 0):

If you have the original installation media, add it as a source and run `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree` to install some drivers that may be hindering your ability to use the wireless adapter.

Comment: The original source install came from a USB stick. What do I do with it? Mount it? Then what?

Comment: do you have a gui?

Comment: No, Ubuntu Server install so no GUI (at least it doesn't boot into one)

Comment: is there no way for you to access a normal network at all?

Comment: Only with a Windows PC at another location nearby

Comment: hold on a little bit I'll see if there is something I can dig up

Comment: I'm not finding much on how to do it. Is there any way you could bring it home or something and hook it up to internet? the whole package is maybe 30mb at most, and takes maybe 5 minutes to install tops

Comment: or I might be able to make a deb file you can use. what kind of dongle is it?

Comment: The dongle is in the OP in the link. Can't really move it, it's mounted

Comment: I don't usually like referring to just the link without including the contents of it but have you tried this? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1744371

Comment: But... I don't have make. That thread is saying to use make.

Comment: I think you can get that as a deb package as well. Do you have a 1 tb hard drive?

Comment: My HDD on Ubuntu is 300GB

Comment: I mean do you have an external 1tb drive and a bit of time on your hands? or do you have another system that is ubuntu based that you could download the packages on?

Comment: I have a USB stick that big, yes. I do not have Ubuntu anywhere else. All Windows.

Comment: you could create a partial copy of the repo with only the parts you need with probably about a gb or so, so even on a usb. I wonder how you would add the source though. Check how to do that and you're good to go

Comment: can you load a livecd on another machine?

Comment: I don't have any CD drives in any machines, haha. Not sure what to do

Comment: really not sure either. Do you have a machine you could borrow? or a liveusb or something? to do this you need an ubuntu machine (even virtualized) that's connected to the internet and has a drive that you can access after running dpkg-repack on the necessary packages

Comment: Maybe, but that's way too much work. It'd be easier to just wipe it and use CentOS which comes with `make` which I'm kinda considering now :/

Comment: you could use linux mint or do a normal install and after configuring it uninstall x and the gui..